# How to use a dynamically defined field handle in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, entrymodel, entries-field

I'm trying to make a plugin more generally usable (so others could use it). For my own use, it uses a category field called 'mainCategory' but I'd like that the field handle could be specified in the plugin settings.

What I imagine is:

```
$url = $entry->mainCategory->last()->uri;
```

becomes:

```
$plugin = craft()->plugins->getPlugin('myPlugin');
$settings = $plugin->getSettings();
$fieldHandle = $settings->categoryFieldHandle;

$url = $entry->getField($fieldHandle)->last()->uri;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't `$entry->$fieldHandle->last()->uri` work?

Comment: It does indeed. I had no idea you could put a variable after the `->`. Thank you.

Comment: Cool... I'll go ahead and add that as an answer if you want to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
$entry->$fieldHandle->last()->uri;
```